# поиск подстроки в строке в java

Tags: java

Не могу написать алгоритм поиска подстроки в строке. Бьюсь неделю но ничего не выходит.

Нужно вывести на консоль индекс начало искомой последовательности.

```
 char[] arr = {'F', 'U', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'M', 'E', '!' ,'!'};
 char[] val = {'M', 'E', '!'}; 
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  for (int j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] == val[j + i]) { 
      System.out.println("Найдено: " + i);
    } else { 
      if (arr[j] != val[j + i]) { 
       System.out.println(i); 
      } 
    } 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: char[] arr = {'F', 'U', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'M', 'E', '!' ,'!'};
        char[] val = {'M', 'E', '!'};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] == val[j + i]) {
                    System.out.println("Найдено: " + i);
                }
                else {
                    if (arr[j] != val[j + i]) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: чтобы искать подстроку в строке нужно иметь строку и подстроку. А у тебя этого нет.

Comment: А еще в программировании очень помогает чтение ошибок, которые выдаются при выполнении.

Answer (score 1):

Если подойдёт вариант с использованием методов класса String, то вот:

```
    char[] arr = {'F', 'U', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'M', 'E', '!', '!'};
    char[] val = {'M', 'E', '!'};
    String strArr = String.copyValueOf(arr); // получаем строку из массива символов arr
    String strVal = String.copyValueOf(val); // получаем строку из массива символов val
    if(strArr.contains(strVal)) { // проверяем содержит строка подстроку
        System.out.println(strArr.indexOf(strVal)); // выводим индекс первого вхождения указанной подстроки в этой строке 
    }
```

Если нужен алгоритм то, возможно это подойдёт:

```
    char[] arr = {'!', '!', 'C', 'K', '!', 'r', 'r', ' ', 'M', 'E', '!', '!', 'r'};
    char[] val = {'r', ' ', 'M', 'E', '!', '!', 'r'};

    if (arr.length < val.length) { // если длина массива arr меньше длины массива val, то выходим
        System.out.println("Не найдено");
        return;
    } else {
        if (arr.length == val.length && arr[0] != val[0]) { // если длины массивов равны, но символы под  индексом 0 не равны, то выходим
            System.out.println("Не найдено");
            return;
        }
        firstloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != val[0]) { // проходимся по массиву arr и ищем первое вхождение первого символа подстроки
                continue; // если текущий символ не равен первому символу подстроки, то продолжаем итерироваться
            } else { // идём сюда, если обнаружено вхождение первого символа подстроки в строке
                final int index = i; // здесь сохраняем индекс первого вхождения первого символа подстроки
                if ((index + val.length) > arr.length) { // от индекса до arr.length должно быть количество символов не большее, чем val.length 
                    System.out.println("Не найдено");
                    return;
                } else {
                    int count = 1; // счётчик для начала итерации по массиву val с индекса 1, так как символ с индексом 0 уже нашли в строке
                    while (count < val.length) { // 
                        if (arr[index + count] != val[count]) {
                            continue firstloop; // если символы не равны начинаем всё заново с цикла с меткой firstloop
                        } else {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Найдено. Индекс начала искомой последовательности: " + index);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Не найдено");
    }
```